# How to find a particular process from the task manager?

Tags: windows-8

Running windows 8 on a local server, creates so many processes inside. Looking for a sophisticated way (Like we search for apps in start menu) to have a particular process out from the bunch of processes inside task manager of windows 8.

1. Is there any such feature available, which I don't know?
2. Do we need to have a 3rd party app for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of typing in the Process list to select them by name I don't know an option.

However, you could install [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which allows you to select a process by pointing to a window:

[image]

Comment: Sorting is just a common idea, which is not helping me out much. Moreover I dont have idea about Process Explorer app that you may talking about.

Comment: Joey answered both your questions (1. NO, 2. ProcessExplorer from Sysinternals), and I support it. Link came later, a quick google was no problem for me though ;)

Comment: To be fair, the link appeared after an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have found article on the same. I don't think I need to explain anything else.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/deep-troubleshooting-with-the-windows-8-task-manager-processes-tab/6354

Comment: Yes you do. Links go stale (and you posted a broken link), and if the link went down, your answer would be useless. You may want to paraphrase and include essential parts of the process.